# Neo4j Casual Cluster on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, neo4j, amazon-ecs

I am trying to stand up a Neo4j Casual Cluster on AWS. I chose ECS over fargate and elastic beanstalk because I want to enjoy the cost savings of not using an elastic load balancer. Those things are expensive.

Is casual clustering (taking advantage of the built in neo4j routing) the best way to go?

The issue I am having is with Docker. I cannot seem to get the neo4j instance to connect to the other instances if I do not set up a custom bridge network on docker.

Has anyone else been successful creating a docker casual cluster on a cloud system?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I think it's not recommended to use Docker for your database nodes. AWS have a prebuilt AMI for neo4j that you can use - https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07D441G55?qid=1528993169661&sr=0-2&ref_=srh_res_product_title